# Click button when available with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need a script that waits for this button to be available and then clicks it, can someone explain how I can do this?

This is the button code:

```
<input id="cashrun_buy" class="cashrun-green" value="Buy now!" type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready( function() { 
     setInterval(function() {
          if($("#cashrun_buy").length>0)
          {
            $("#cashrun_buy").click();
          }
    }, 5000);
 });
```

Comment: a `setInterval` would be much better here, IMHO.

Comment: Not working for me. http://tny.cz/a2e66b80 <-- some more code..
What I have: http://tny.cz/b446b8ee

Comment: Still doesn't do anything for me?